# Why does kmeans give poor accuraccy rate?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, k-means

In my term project, I use MillonSongDataset and have extracted 84 features that do not include any NaN values or 0 variance. While, KNN works amazingly, kmeans has an accuraccy rate of 9%. Why might it be the case? can anyone enlighten me please?

Comment: How are you calculating accuracy with K-means? Please share some code.

Comment: K-means is an unsupervised clustering algorithm. You cannot compare the cluster allocations to true class labels.